# Error in SQL syntax using Java

Tags: java, sql

```
public boolean setgame(int botid, int gameid, String name, String ip, int spoofed, int reserved, int loadingtime, int left, String leftreason, int team, int colour, String spoofedrealm) {
    try {
        Connection connection = connection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO gameplayers (id, botid, gameid, name, ip, spoofed, reserved, loadingtime, left, leftreason, team, colour, spoofedrealm) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        statement.setInt(1, botid);
        statement.setInt(2, gameid);
        statement.setString(3, name);
        statement.setString(4, ip);
        statement.setInt(5, spoofed);
        statement.setInt(6, reserved);
        statement.setInt(7, loadingtime);
        statement.setInt(8, left);
        statement.setString(9, leftreason);
        statement.setInt(10, team);
        statement.setInt(11, colour);
        statement.setString(12, spoofedrealm);
        statement.execute();
        connectionReady(connection);
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        if (Main.DEBUG) {
        }
        Main.println("[SQLThread] Unable to add bot ban to MySQL database: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

I created a main method to add all data and I can't see any error in the `insert` statement.

I am getting this error:

```
[SQLThread] Fail: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left, leftreason, team, colour, spoofedrealm) VALUES (NULL, 2, 146, 'Teste', '120.32' at line 1
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem i have many other public class and everyone has NULL in id field

Comment: Have you tested the SQL code directly on the SQL Server? Additionally, can you specific which SQL Engine you are using? SQL Server, MySQL, Postgre, etc. - there are certain subtleties between each in the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT` is [reserved word in MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) (as in `LEFT OUTER JOIN...`). You need to use quotes around it to use it as an identifier.

Better yet, consider renaming the field to not use a reserved word as an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT` is a reserved word in MySQL; you have to escape it:

```
INSERT INTO gameplayers (
     id, botid, gameid, name, ip, spoofed, reserved, loadingtime, `left`, ...
                                                        ----------^----^
```